# How do I merge two questions in one?

Tags: discussion, merging, closed-questions

Sorry if I just overlooking something, but I don't see how to merge two questions in one.

I asked question [Can be profitable to migrate from Windows to Linux in a small business?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47865/can-be-profitable-to-migrate-from-windows-to-linux-in-a-small-business) which was by opinion of others confusing. In order to improve my question I re-ask it as was suggested in comments. Thus I created another question [What factors contribute to the expense of migrating to Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47898/what-factors-contribute-to-the-expense-of-migrating-to-linux) and intended to delete the old one. Then the new one was marked as a duplicate (of course it is, because is improvement of the old poorly asked question).

In the commentary to duplicate closure is written *answers may be merged with another identical question*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The original has been closed and does not appear to have actual answers. nothing would be merged.

Comment: **1)** I ask this question because I didn't find the general merging guideline. Does that mean that there is no general way how to do that and all merging is done manually?  
**2)** Yes there was my original idea. Create new question and delete the old one. But since the old one is now closed. I cannot delete it.
**3)** In the comments of the old question I was told that it doesn't work that way. So I'm just wondering which way it works?

Comment: if you want we can delete the old one, but yes the way to do a merge is manual and done by a mod.

Comment: Fine. Then delete the old one please. Thank you.

Comment: It's been closed

Comment: So the old question is gone. And whether the new question is on topic or not is currently [under discussion](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/are-questions-about-linux-in-the-context-of-business-or-society-on-topic). Can the new question be re-opened, at least until the discussion resolves (at which point it could be closed, correctly, as 'off-topic' if necessary)?

Answer (score 1):

If both questions *do* have useful answers, flag one and a mod can merge them.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that the flag is used for that. Thanks.